# Request to specific nested url by DS.store methods

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have following code in route:

```
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('user', params.id)
  }
```

And how expected, it request to:

**/users/{somethingId}**

But my route in external api is nested and it looks like:

**/partners/{somethingId}/users**

Because of this, i need make something request like:

**/partners/{somethingId}/users** or **/partners/{somethingId}/users/{userId}**

I tried Ember's relationships but it didn't help me. I got url with params:

```
return this.store.findRecord('partner', params.id, {include:'users'});
// api/partners/5?include=users
```

I also tried method `store.adapterFor` and it was changing namespace of my adapter immediately before each request:

```
this.store.adapterFor('application').set('namespace', '/api/partners/' + params.id);
```

But making this thing all time before each request would be dirty, so I don't want going this way.

I know i can use something like ajax-ember but i'd like to use DS.store with adapters. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create adapter for `user` model and override [urlForFindRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.BuildURLMixin.html#method_urlForFindRecord)

app/adapters/user.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  urlForFindRecord(id, modelName, snapshot) {
    let baseUrl = this.buildURL();
    return `${baseUrl}/partners/${id}/users`;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know something more versatile? Sometimes i will need createRecord or update or even use this on other nested model.

Comment: for example, for update, I need pass two ids to make request like this: '/partners/{somethingId}/users/{userId}'

Comment: You can pass this in findRecord `{ adapterOptions: this.get('orderId") }`, then in `urlForFindRecord` you can access that at `snapshot.adapterOptions`

Comment: You can look at this [buildUrl method](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.11.0/addon/-private/adapters/build-url-mixin.js#L54) where they are allowing to customizing url for ember-data request

Comment: Ohh snapshot, I should check this before! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, ember data does not support nested urls for resources, there is no easy solution. You have 3 options:

1. As suggested in other answer, create adapter for each of such resources and override buildUrl method.
2. Give up on ember data and use `Ember.$.ajax` for requests. You still can use ember data for caching (describing models as usual and using methods like DS.Store.pushPayload, DS.Store.hasRecordForId, DS.Store.peekRecord, DS.Store.peekAll).
3. Change backend to support endpoints that will work with ember data.

If 3 is not an option, I suggest 2. In my opinion, ember data is too restrictive for real life projects, especially for cases when you can't rewrite backend (have no control over it).